# long list in c# windows phone.What are the ways to display LISTs in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to display a list in windows phone. But each list item is so long that it is displayed only a part by using a listbox control. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you draw the desired UI and post links here? It would be easier to understand what you want and why you cannot use List control.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a `ListBox`/`LongListSelector` is to show a list of items that wouldn't fit on the screen at once. The user can scroll through all the items so it sounds like it's doing what you'd expect it to. If each item is too long for your deign plans then you have to change your item template design.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could use a `StackPanel` or the `WrapPanel` from the Phone toolkit http://phone.codeplex.com/. You can put a ScrollViewer in a custom control that allows for scrolling but these will all just simulate the fundamentals of a ListBox.